# Angular 2: Using service to share data between components

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-services, angular2-observables

I am trying to use a service to define a shared resource `client` between several views.  I first select the `client` from an index and set it:

```
itemTapped(event, client) {
  this.clientService.get(`/${client.id}?model=client`, this.current_user.auth_token)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.clientService.setClient(data)
        this.navCtrl.push(ClientGenericPage, {
          client_id: data['id'],
          tab: 'profile',
          current_user: this.current_user
        });
      },
      err => { 
        this.clientService.handleResponse("Ut oh.. Could not locate the client !"),
        this.clientService.hideLoader()
      },
      () => this.clientService.hideLoader()
    )
}

export class ClientService {

  private client = new Subject<any>();


  constructor (private http: Http, private toastCtrl: ToastController, public storage: Storage ) {

  }

  setClient(client) {
    this.client.next(client)
  }

  getClient() {
    return this.client.asObservable();
  }

  get(url, token):Observable<Response> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("authentication", token );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let final_url = `${this.baseUrl}${url}`

    return this.http.get(final_url, options)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError)
  }
}
```

Then I try to get the client that was just set and subscribe to it so that I can detect changes to `client` in this view and its siblings:

```
this.clientService.getClient()
  .subscribe(
    val => {
      console.log(val)
      this.client = val
    },
    err => console.log(err),
    () => {}
)
```

but this call to `getClient()` never returns an error or anything at all.  What am I doing wrong with my observable?

EDIT:  Here is the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-client-details',
  templateUrl: 'client-details.html',
  providers: [FilterObject, ClientService]
})
export class ClientDetailsPage {
  client:any;
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams, 
    private filterObject: FilterObject, 
    public http: Http,
    public modalController: ModalController,
    private clientService: ClientService,
    private app: App
  ) {

  this.clientService.getClient()
    .subscribe(
      val => {
        console.log(val)
        this.client = val
      },
      err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log("completed")
    )
}
```

Comment: Where do you provide the service?

Comment: in the component where I am trying to display the data.  The same component where `this.clientService.getClient()` is called

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `val => this.client = val`

Comment: I thought it would take the data returned from `getClient()` and set it to `this.client`

Comment: I also added changed the line `() => {}` to `() => { console.log("completed") }` and never see that in the console

Comment: I'll also add that when I log `this.client` in `setClient()` it shows that the `Observable` has 0 `observers`.

Comment: I changed that line once I realized the error you were pointing out.

Comment: can you post your component class code

Comment: I tried making a plunker and got this far http://plnkr.co/edit/f1qZvw01sswb3m04RhQT?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why are you defining ClientService  in the component class. is ClientService related single component ?

you need provide ClientService in the app.module.ts and inject clientservice in the component class. if you provide clientservice in the component it will create different instance for the component

**app.module.ts**

```
 providers: [ ClientService  ],
```

**ClientDetailsPage.ts**    remove providers: [ ClientService  ]

```
{
constructor(clientService  : ClientService  ) { 

  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize I shouldn't have it there.  Removing it didn't solve the problem though.

Comment: can you create plunker.

Comment: I've tried and can't get it working.  Can you provide a link with a plunker that uses services?

Comment: I've gotten this far: http://plnkr.co/edit/f1qZvw01sswb3m04RhQT?p=preview

Comment: fixed couple of issues. working plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/OCaUBgnGj6AenWyeWLxA?p=preview  important points 1) remove client service provider from home component(try to read dependency  injection) 2) used behavior subject  instead of subject. Next time onward explain question clearly and it took me lot of time understand your question and plunker. one more thing is  your plunker no match to your question (there is no getClient function itself in plunker)

Comment: I was doing my best to recreate it in a simpler manner.  I'm new to Angular so it's difficult for me to express my question when I'm unfamiliar.  Doing my best

Comment: I hope my solution working for you. try to do tour of heros project in Angular site. it will give good understating about component, service and observable.

Comment: It did!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using BehaviorSubject instead of Subject, the unique change it you need provide a default value. Same error I fixed with that, but with no problem found.